# Could the force accelerating a particle be derived as the gradient of the spatial distribution of kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, potential

If a point mass is accelerated by a force $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$ the kinetic energy $T$ could be derived from

$$T = \int_{\vec{r_0}}^{\vec{r}}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}} = \int_{\vec{r_0}}^{\vec{r}}{m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot d\vec{r}} = \int_{\vec{v_0}}^{\vec{v}}{m \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v}} = \frac{m}{2}\vec{v}^2 $$ with $T(\vec{r_0}) = 0$ and $\vec{v_0} = \vec{0}$.

In the same way if a point mass is trapped e.g. in a gravity potential $V$ the force acting on the particle is given by $\vec{F_g} = - \nabla V$ and the potential could be calculated through

$$ V(\vec{r}) = -\int_{\vec{r_0}}^{\vec{r}}{\vec{F_g} \cdot d\vec{r}} $$ and $V(\vec{r_0}) = 0$ at a certain reference point $\vec{r_0}$. Does this mean by analogy $\vec{F} = \nabla T = \frac{m}{2} \nabla \vec{v}^2(\vec{r})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, but **there is a big problem.**

Velocity is pretty much always written as a function of time $\vec{v} = \vec{v}(t)$,  so you can't easily take its gradient.

What you could do is write $\nabla \vec{v}^2 = \frac{d \vec{v}^2}{d t} \nabla{t}$, but it's much easier to find the potential.

Comment: Linear velocity is a function of position (vector field) in mechanics, and the field changes with time according to [Spatial Acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_acceleration) field.

Comment: @ja72 Well, I did not know that. But still, for gravitational problems, velocity is **usually** defined as a function of time., right? I'll look into this, thanks.